# Responsive menu issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(First I'd like to apologize if my English is bad sometimes, I'm French, so it's kinda difficult to explain everything in details )

I'm working on a personal website, but i got a problem with my responsive navigation.

I made a media query for screen size under 1024px.

When I'm above 1024px, I have my regular navigation bar made with a list.
When I'm under 1024px, I got the small menu logo that appears, and a click event on it makes the whole menu appear and disappear.

But the problem is that if my menu is closed and I expand my window above 1024 pixels, the list isn't visible, and I don't know how to deal with that problem.

Here is my code :

```
        <nav class="fixed_nav">
        <div id="nav_left">
            <img id="logo_nav" src="img/mini_trombi.png" alt="logo"/>
            <p id="txt_nav">123</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="topnav">
            <div id="show_n_hide_nav" class="responsive_link_bg">
                <li><a id="top_nav_link" class="nav_links" href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
                <hr class="responsive_separator">
                <li><a class="nav_links" href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
                <hr class="responsive_separator">
                <li><a class="nav_links" href="#">ITEM 3</a></li>
            </div>
            <li class="icon">
                <a div id="button_nav" class="menu_icon" href="javascript:void(0);">&#9776;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Jquery for the click:

```
$(function(){
  $("#button_nav").click(function () {
      if(!$("#show_n_hide_nav").is(":visible")){
          $("#show_n_hide_nav").slideDown("slow");
      } else {
          $("#show_n_hide_nav").slideUp("slow");
      }
  });
});
```

In my css, I hide the original list under 1024 pixels, and show it with the help of jquery when the users clicks on the menu logo.

Again, sorry if it's hard to understand.

Comment: Aside ... your HTML is invalid an `ul` element only allows `li` items as direct childs

Comment: Including your css as well might be a good idea ;-)

Comment: Woops, didn't see that ! thanks DaniP !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you solve the invalid HTML, you can try this:

The problem is the `slideUp/Down` function from Jquery sets inline the `display` property to the element itself, then when you `slideUp` and resize the browser the element is still hidden with inline style:

```
<li id="show_n_hide_nav" class="responsive_link_bg" style="display: none;">
```

You can solve it adding this mediaquerie to force the element be block over `1024`:

```
@media (min-width:1025px) {
  #show_n_hide_nav {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

[**Check this example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oy0zwae0/)

Comment: Oh, perfect ! Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Glad to help U @mnX_87

Answer (score 0):

You better toggle class and add css transitions to do slide effect and if you're above 1024, just ignore the `show` class.

```
$("#button_nav").click(function () {
   $("#show_n_hide_nav").toggleClass("show");
});
```

If you still want to use `slideDown()`/`slideUp()`, you have to bind `$(window).resize()` event and check whether the window is above/under 1024px.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try with that ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $("#button_nav").click(function () {
      if(!$("#show_n_hide_nav").is(":visible")){
          $("#show_n_hide_nav").slideDown("slow");
      } else {
          $("#show_n_hide_nav").slideUp("slow");
      }
  });
});
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($(window).width() > 1024){
      $("#show_n_hide_nav").show();
   }
});
```

On window resize you have to check window size and show nav.